# How can I detect if OnClick is finished before going into CalendarCont?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have some code into a function called when button is clicked. This function saves into store some information after doing some axios request. As axios request is slow, HTML continues even though the function has not finished yet, so the information sended to CalendarCont is not complete. I need some way to ensure that onTeamAdd function has finished before continueing.

I have used async await into the function so that the actions into it (including axios request) are made in the correct order.

I have ckecked via console.logs that onTeamAdd function has not finished when CalendarCont is called.

The following code is into a react Component.

```
return (
    <div className="mainComponent" >
        <div className="page_title">Calendar</div>
            <div className="search_component" >
                <div className="combobox">
                  <label className="labelBox">Teams</label>
                  <Search
                      items={teams}
                      onItemSelect={onTeamSelect}
                      value={selectedTeams}
                      placeholder="Type to filter teams..."
                  />
                  <button
                   className="addBttn"
                   onClick={() => onTeamAdd(selectedTeams)}>
                       Add
                  </button>
              </div>
              <div className="calendar_component">
                  <CalendarCont abstences={allAbstences} teams= 
                   {addedItems.addedTeams} issues={issues} releases= 
                   {releases} />
              </div>
          </div>
      );

  }

}
```

This is what is printed in console when I run. First 2 prints and last 3 are into onTeamAdd function, but the Calendar [Promise] one is into Calendar component, so I can know that CalendarCont is called before returning from onTeamAdd function.

Before await
into await
Calendar [Promise]
request is Done!
after await
Returning

Comment: Do you use some kind of call that returns a promise? In which case you can use finally() - perhaps set some state there like loaded: true (whereas loaded: false is set in the constructor for this class). Then it would be a matter of if (this.state.loaded) { } to check if the method has 'finished').

Comment: This is a very specific question. Could you generalise it, so it'd be both relevant for future generations and more clear for potential answerers?

Comment: Like general question I can say that what I'm looking for is a way to stop all untill onTeamAdd function has finished

Answer (score 0):

Add a `loading` state that you change to `false` after the await on the axios call. Then conditionally render the `<CalendarCont />` component based on that state.

```
onTeamAdd = teams => {
  // your code including the await axios call
  this.setState({ loading: false });
}
```

And then on your render:

```
<div className="calendar_component">
  {!this.state.loading && 
    <CalendarCont 
      abstences={allAbstences} 
      teams={addedItems.addedTeams} 
      issues={issues} 
      releases={releases} 
    />}
</div>
```

You could also look at addedTeams and conditionally render the `<CalendarCont />` component based on that.

Comment: This does not work for me, somehow it still crashes